# Spring Async: How to call spring hateoas ControllerLinkBuilder inside Async method

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-hateoas, spring-async

I am calling ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo method inside a spring Async method and it fails to find the current request.

```
service.setUrl(linkTo(Controller.class, Controller.METHOD_GET,
                headers.getFirst(HEADER_SOURCE), id).toString());
```

Exception:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find current request via RequestContextHolder
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find current request via RequestContextHolder
```

Answer (score 0):

Complementing the _Manan reponse, You can set the attribute inheritance to true on your properties file. Please add the following line:

```
spring.freemarker.request-context-attribute=true
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried to reconstruct your problem and weren't able to. Have you tried using something like the following?

```
linkTo(methodOn(EnvironmentRequestStateTransitioner.class)
    .approveRegistrationRequest(23L))
    .withRel("approve")
```

That worked fine for me using `spring-boot-starter-parent` version `1.3.2.RELEASE`.

Comment: I had to make the `RequestAttributes` inheritable.  `RequestAttributes currentRequestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
        RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(currentRequestAttributes, Boolean.TRUE);`

Comment: You had to do this to get it working or to produce the problem described in your question?

Comment: I had to do that to get it working. It basically exposes the `RequestAttributes` as inheritable for child threads.